# jest.setTimeout is not working in setupFiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am using Jest for testing my rest API. Most of my API endpoints take more than 5 seconds to return, so I need to increase the default timeout of 5000ms specified in Jest.

I have 2 test files, suppose:
foo.test.js
bar.test.js

Now, I can get rid of the timeout error by following 2 ways:

1. Setting timeout values greater than 5000, as the 3rd argument to `test` or `it` methods. This works fine, but I need to update all of my existing test cases.
2. Adding `jest.setTimeout(20000);` at the top of each of my test files. This also works fine. But still, it requires me to update all my existing test files.

I found out that I can instead specify `jest.setTimeout(20000);` in a separate file, and point to that in [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) configuration option for jest in package.json. I did this but the timeout error of exceeding 5000ms started coming up again. My setupFile is being loaded correctly, which I checked by adding some `console.log` statements to this. But it seems `jest.setTimeout(20000)` is not having any effect on the test cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) for `setupFilesAfterEnv`:

> `setupFiles` executes before the test framework is installed in the environment

(That information should probably be added to the `setupFiles` section of the docs as well.)

---

`setupFiles` runs *before* the test framework is installed.  I'm a bit surprised that `jest.setTimeout` is defined within a setup file.  In any case, calling `jest.setTimeout` doesn't work right from within a file in `setupFiles`.

Instead, use `setupFilesAfterEnv` which runs

> immediately after the test framework has been installed in the environment

---

Note that `setupFilesAfterEnv` was [introduced in version `24.0.0`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2400).

If you are using an earlier version of `Jest` use the older `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` instead.

Comment: hey thanks @brian-lives-outdoors. I had fixed this issue using exactly how you mentioned. First tried with `setupFilesAfterEnv`, which wasn't supported as I'm using `23.x.x`, and finally got it to work with `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`. Thanks for your help.